# How to dynamically number theorems?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I am writing an introduction. I want to reference theorems and so on which come later. I want to do something like the following.

`\newtheorem*{thmcustom}[1]{Theorem #1}`

Then `\begin{thmcustom}[3.2.1] .. \end{thmcustom}` would print out **Thereom** 3.2.1:... (In general I would have a `\ref{thm:whatever}` as opposed to the 3.2.1, but anyway.)

Of course, this doesn't work. Is there a way which I can do this?

(I have a hideous hack of doing `\newtheorem*{thmA}{Theorem \ref{thm:thmA}}` for each theorem I want to reference.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{thmA}{Theorem \ref{thm:thmA}}

\begin{document}
The same theorem which comes later:
\begin{thmA}
This is a theorem.
\end{thmA}

The original statement of the theorem.
\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:thmA}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

This is awful! So anything will be better...)

Comment: What do you use to produce your theorems, since any working solution would have to be particular to the package. In fact, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)... that would be awesome.

Comment: If you are using `amsthm` (or e.g. `amsart`, which loads `amsthm` automatically), with `\newtheorem*{thmcustom}{Theorem}`, then you can do `\begin{thmcustom}[3.2.1] . . . \end{thmcustom}` to get "**Theorem** (3.2.1)", which is an admittedly unsatisfactory solution that is at least easy.

Comment: I am using amsthm.

Comment: (And I have added in the requested example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (not so dirty) hack, based on the `amsthm` package.
The `theoremff` environment is used for "fast-forward" theorems.
The first (optional) argument is the theorem's name.
The second argument is the theorem's label.

Notice that theorems are not **dynamically** numbered, I don't think you would want that!  They are numbered as usual, but you are able to "fast-forward" some of them, using of course the same number that they will have later on.  (Indeed, "fast-forward" is probably misleading, as you may equally well use this for theorems that have already appeared.)  I hope I did not misinterpret your intentions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theoremaux}{Theorem \theoremauxnum}
\gdef\theoremauxnum{1}

\newenvironment{theoremff}[2][]{%
  \def\theoremauxnum{\ref{#2}}
  \begin{theoremaux}[#1]
}{%
  \end{theoremaux}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Here are the two theorems that we will prove:

\begin{theoremff}[Progress]{thm:progress}
Progress theorem.
\end{theoremff}

\begin{theoremff}[Preservation]{thm:preservation}
Preservation theorem.
\end{theoremff}

\section{Metatheory}
And here are their proofs:

\begin{theorem}[Progress]
\label{thm:progress}
Progress theorem.
\begin{proof}
Easy.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Preservation]
\label{thm:preservation}
Preservation theorem.
\begin{proof}
Trivial.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This is what you get for the document above.

[image: result]